# efficent way of casting or converting vector of atomic int to vector of int

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, c++17, std

I do have a vector of integer that I want to ensure increment operations happening thread-safe, so I used `std::vector<std::atomic<int>>` after all parallel increments I need non-atomic vector `std::vector<int>`. Is there an efficient way to do so, without copying? The vector is very large and performance is very important.

Comment: Note that `std::atomic<int>` isn't free - if you truly are only incrementing integers from different threads you'll likely see much better performance if you use a vector per thread and combine them later.

Comment: @rlp interesting point. Maybe I should wrap the vector in my own thread-safe container.

Comment: @NateEldredge Could you explain a little more? Maybe by an example.

Comment: @AMCoded: Never mind, I was mistaken about how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, atomic operations are a property of the object itself, not of how you access it. As far as the object model is concerned, `atomic<int>` has no real relationship to `int` save the fact that you can convert one to another. You cannot transform an `atomic<int>` into an `int`; you can only create a new object with the same value.

Answer (score -1):

I almost forgot that for increment operations, another option is to use __sync_fetch_and_add() instead of getting into trouble using atomic variables.
This is not an actual answer to the casting or converting part of the question but for those who are looking for a thread-safe alternative for const increment operations, This might be useful.